# Python plot category on a day axis

Tags: python, plotly

Hello Guys I have a data set of Date, Category, and Quantity, I want to plot both date and category on the x-axis and quantity on the y axis. that is a plot of Quantity vs Category for each day in the data frame.

[image: viz] [image: data]

Comment: What did you try? Can you provide your best-effort code and some test data (as text, not as image)?  Did you look into seaborn, e.g. `sns.barplot(data=..., x='date', y='quantity', hue='category')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- question is tagged as **plotly** hence a plotly answered
- using this documented approach https://plotly.com/python/categorical-axes/#multicategorical-axes
- have simulated a dataframe that has same structure as image in your question
- have deliberately used strings for dates and interval index

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# simulate dataframe shown in question
df = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        [pd.date_range("7-feb-2022", "17-feb-2022"), range(1, 51, 1)],
        names=["Date", "Category"],
    ),
    data=np.random.uniform(1, 25, 550),
    columns=["Quantity"],
).reset_index()

df["Category"] = pd.cut(df["Category"], bins=[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50]).astype(str)
df = df.groupby(["Date", "Category"]).sum()

# https://plotly.com/python/categorical-axes/#multicategorical-axes
go.Figure(
    go.Bar(
        x=[
            df.index.get_level_values("Date").strftime("%Y-%m-%d").tolist(),
            df.index.get_level_values("Category").tolist(),
        ],
        y=df["Quantity"],
    )
)
```

[image]